# Passing data from blade view to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use `Form::open(['action' => 'Controller@method']);` in blade to pass data from view to controller. Then I got an error:

> Action App\Http\Controllers\Controller@method not defined.

That's right since my Controller is at this address:

> App\Modules\Somethings\Controllers\

So, how can I do to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the fully qualified namespace to the template?

Comment: Is that your idea: `Form::open(['action' => 'App\Modules\Somethings\Controllers\Controller@method']);`

I tried. The error became `Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Modules\Somethings\Controllers\Controller@method not defined.`

Comment: Wait, hang on, shouldn't the form action lead to a url that actually leads to a controller? What laravel version are you using?

Comment: Why exactly wouldn't you use routes?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.3. And i'm new to laravel so i don't know how to use routes well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way.

1. first create a route for this in routes.php file

   `Route::any('first/second/{id}', [
       'uses' => 'App\Modules\Somethings\Controllers@method'
   ]);`
2. Then use that routes url in form

   `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'first/second/5', 'method' => 'put']) !!}`

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by using routes and not controller@method.

In your routes.php define a resource pointing at your controller

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController', ['before' => 'csrf']);
```

Then you can use the URL::route() method to get the right route.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => URL::route('posts.update', [$post->id]), 'method' => 'put', 'files' => false]) !!}
```

To see all your routes and how they are aliased run the following artisan command:

L5.x

```
php artisan route:list
```

L4.x

```
php artisan routes
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the file name is problem. Laravel is basically provide default Controller also.  Why not you change the name and try with that new name or full path.

You will get routes file from routes folder also and use [laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Form::model
```

instead. 
Example:

```
Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['UserController@update', $user->id], 'files' => true]) 
// do you form stuff
Form::close()
```